# What is the difference between a Method and MetaMethod in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, method-invocation

The API docs here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaMethod.html

Explain a MetaMethod as the following:

> [A MetaMethod] represents a Method on a Java object a little like [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html?is-external=true) except
>   without using reflection to invoke the method

What exactly do the docs mean by "a [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html?is-external=true) without using reflection" for invocation?

Comment: The parser probably replaces it to calling the method directly on the object variable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the reference, but i think i read somewhere they use [`Reflectors`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/Reflector.html).